# Similar questions. One upvoted many times, while other is downvoted

Tags: discussion

I am surprised to see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011339/how-do-you-make-a-http-request-with-c) asks for libraries/tools (which could "tend to attract opinionated answers") but it is well received and upvoted.

But when I asked [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27733618/accessing-internet-without-using-wininet-dll) just in other words/context, it was downvoted and also has been voted to close.

Why?

Comment: Have a look at the date the question was posted.... rules change over time.

Comment: Has it been almost *six years* already? This "new year" baloney needs to stop.

Comment: One could omit "are there any libraries that do this" from the older question, and it becomes plain "how to do X in Y".

Comment: Same applies to my question.

Comment: Well, you are in the best position to edit it. The "on-hold" message recommends you to "describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: You have a problem with web connectivity.  You suggest it may be due to malware, which it may, (or may be due loads of other reasons) and ask for another library.   Apart from the XY-problemness of it all, asking for libs is a specific close-reason.

Comment: As hard as I look, I can't see him asking for a library or a tool.  He had a menial task to perform with the wrong language and asks how to do it.  SO had to deal with this kind of stuff in the early days, it wasn't asked before.  Thank heavens that's all done.

Comment: @HansPassant _"Is there any third party (may be open source) library available to do this?"_ - how do you not see this? Or are you talking about the question from '09?

Comment: Your question was closed for legitimate reasons. You requested a recommendation for a third party library to download HTTP content. Questions of this type are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Not sure what the issue is here.